# Insert WMS layer into a WebGIS with qgis2web

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis2web, web-gis

I created a small webgis with the plugin qgis2web. I also added a wms layer but when I go to view the webgis, this layer is not displayed, why? I would like to insert this WMS layer: http://rsdi.regione.basilicata.it/maps/ctr_raster

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/qgis2web.css">
    <style>
    html, body, #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
    <script src="js/qgis2web_expressions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/leaflet.rotatedMarker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/leaflet.pattern.js"></script>
    <script src="js/leaflet-hash.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Autolinker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/rbush.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/labelgun.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/labels.js"></script>
    <script src="js/leaflet.wms.js"></script>
    <script src="data/cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1.js"></script>
    <script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
        zoomControl:true, maxZoom:28, minZoom:1
    }).fitBounds([[40.8706174062,15.4763824142],[40.9724805093,15.7125025513]]);
    var hash = new L.Hash(map);
    map.attributionControl.addAttribution('<a href="https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web" target="_blank">qgis2web</a>');
    var bounds_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
    function setBounds() {
    }
    var overlay_CTRRaster_0 = L.WMS.layer("http://rsdi.regione.basilicata.it/maps/ctr_raster", "CTR Raster", {
        format: 'image/png',
        uppercase: true,
        transparent: true,
        continuousWorld : true,
        tiled: true,
        info_format: 'text/html',
        opacity: 1,
        identify: false,
    });
    map.addLayer(overlay_CTRRaster_0);
    function pop_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1(feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = '<table>\
                <tr>\
                    <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['code800'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['code800'])) : '') + '</td>\
                </tr>\
                <tr>\
                    <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['code55'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['code55'])) : '') + '</td>\
                </tr>\
            </table>';
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
    }

    function style_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1_0() {
        return {
            pane: 'pane_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1',
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)',
            dashArray: '',
            lineCap: 'butt',
            lineJoin: 'miter',
            weight: 1.0, 
            fill: true,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fillColor: 'rgba(96,165,82,1.0)',
        }
    }
    map.createPane('pane_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1');
    map.getPane('pane_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1').style.zIndex = 401;
    map.getPane('pane_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
    var layer_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1 = new L.geoJson(json_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1, {
        attribution: '<a href=""></a>',
        pane: 'pane_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1',
        onEachFeature: pop_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1,
        style: style_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1_0,
    });
    bounds_group.addLayer(layer_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1);
    map.addLayer(layer_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1);
    var baseMaps = {};
    L.control.layers(baseMaps,{'<img src="legend/cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1.png" /> cross_tabulation_1800_1955': layer_cross_tabulation_1800_1955_1,"CTR Raster": overlay_CTRRaster_0,}).addTo(map);
    setBounds();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: according to metadata, the WMS url of the CTR is the following: http://basilicata.podis.it/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=../htdocs/0wms/ctrn5000.map&version=1.1.1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The WMS url that I used in QGIS is different and it works normally. Your url is a different cartography compared to what I have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason why, but if I include layer id 0, instead of layer id 1 from that WMS, it works, but layer id 0 does not.

Other things to check: match your project CRS to your layer CRS, and in qgis2web, check "Match project CRS".

Answer (score 0):

If you only use a small extent it might be an easier solution to download the map (e.g. as geotiffs) and add these as layers.

I found another option ([link](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/604)): Create a new XYZ layer using an URL. 
Example URL for OpenTopMap: `https://tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. It should be possible to export this with qgis2web.